# I'm trying to implement external REST APIs in my wordpress website. Can anybody have idea how to do it (whether with a plugin or with programming)

Tags: wordpress, rest

I tried to use one plugin called "WP Data Sync". I am also going through its documentation/ support for the same. I am also having wpbakery page builder in my website. So is there any way that we sync with that also?
Note - We have to sync data in the form of images, image gallery, events listing, and the blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out WP Data Syncs website at https://wpdatasync.com/ and create an account to check out an API key?

I'm not sure about all APIs, but the ones I've used in the past would require me to register with the API's website, get issued an API key and maybe even designate the key to a specific website (your WordPress site in this case) for security reasons. After that, you would then go to your WP site and setup the API there via WP DataSyncs plugin.

I hope I understood your question and that this helps.